# How do you tell if an EF4 entity is new or an existing record?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

In my application I have an entity which is being used essentially as a complex many to many between my User and Project entities.  I am trying to determine how to figure out if my service layer needs to add the entity to the context or attach the entity (for updating an existing entity) and I am at a loss of how.

This is easy to determine for most of my entities because of the `Int` Id field, if it's zero the database hasn't given it an identity value yet.  This is not possible if it's a composite primary key.

Does anyone have any suggestion on how to determine if an instance of an entity is new or an update to an existing record?

**Edit**: I forgot to mention, these entities are POCOs built for code-first, so I don't have an EntityState property on the entity itself.

Comment: Added update to show that these are POCOs, not standard EF entities.

Comment: guess i read your mind, see my answer. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, as the above answers state, you check the **EntityState** for the entity in the OSM.

However, keep in mind this only works for entities attached to the context/graph.

I'm currently working with detached entities (ASP.NET MVC), and because they are not attached to the graph, the EntityState is unchanged.

In this case, i am doing a precautionary call to the DB to grab the entity by the key. If nothing is returned, i do an Add, otherwise i use **ApplyCurrentValues** to override the values, then do **.SaveChanges**

I'm still wondering if this is the correct way, but thought i'd put it out there.

I'm using POCO's which have no change tracking, hence i have to do a bit more work.

Since there is no EntityState for the POCO, you have to manually call into the OSM:

```
var pocosInGraph = ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified)
```

After you Attach/Add, your POCO should be in that collection.

As i said though, if this is for a MVC application, your entities are detached on a HTTP POST, and thus the EntityState will still be unchanged.

In my case, i manually set the EntityState after Attaching:

```
ctx.Attach(poco);
ctx.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(poco, EntityState.Modified);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  I'm using ASP.NET MVC as well, so I guess checking with the DB before attaching or adding is the way to go.

Comment: Cool. Yeah i was noticing if i forgot to bind all properties in my View, it was seeing this as a flag to "clear" these values when i submit the form. I think it's safer to do the call (it's an efficient call anyway).

Answer (score 3):

```
if (x.EntityState == System.Data.EntityState.Added)
//Add
else if (x.EntityState == System.Data.EntityState.Modified)
//Attach
```

for more info

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entitystate.aspx

Comment: `EntityState` is a `FlagsAttribute`; it can *contain* `Added` without being *equal* to it.

Comment: It looks to me that FlagsAttribute was introduced only for the purpose of searching with GetObjectStateEntries. If you try assign a multi-EntityState, you will get InvalidOperationException: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectstatemanager.changeobjectstate.aspx